# Relation of between CPU vCores and spark executor-cores

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ec2

I am launching an EMR cluster with m5.xlarge core nodes as follow:

```
4 vCore, 16 GiB memory, EBS only storage
EBS Storage:200 GiB
```

I am not sure if I run an Spark Job and setting the executor-core parameter such as 2. If this is exactly the same as vCores in my m5.xlarge instances?

Answer (score 0):

each executor's core will use a vCore in your cluster, hence create either 4 executors with 1 core each or 2 executors with 2 cores each or 1 executor with 4 cores. Enjoy!

Comment: It is abit strange.. I had 9 m5.xlarge instances and the total of 36 vcores (plus master node which had 4 vcores), but I could run a spark job with 75 instances each with 2 executor-cores on yarn..

Comment: You must know what are the other services that you are running there, and of course it's necessary to include the driver in your calculation. Do you have 36 vcores in total devided by 9 instances? I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

AWS defines 1 core as 1vCPU for most instances. I believe that's the same as vCore

"“Each vCPU is a hyper-thread of an Intel Xeon core except for T2.”

In other words, for T2 instances, 1 vCPU = 1 physical core. For all others, 1 vCPU = 1 logical core. This can lead to significant performance differences when it comes to multi-threaded, burst CPU usage."

Reference: [https://www.credera.com/insights/whats-in-a-vcpu-state-of-amazon-ec2-in-2018#:~:text=%E2%80%9CEach%20vCPU%20is%20a%20hyper,%2Dthreaded%2C%20burst%20CPU%20usage](https://www.credera.com/insights/whats-in-a-vcpu-state-of-amazon-ec2-in-2018#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CEach%20vCPU%20is%20a%20hyper,%2Dthreaded%2C%20burst%20CPU%20usage).